# NonExistentQueue Error AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to my Queue from Amazon's SQS

```
Error AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue caused by Sender. The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.
```

It is a PHP script that is trying to connect to the queue.

The queue will work for days then I get this message.. Anyone know why they might stop working?

If it helps I am using rightscale to manage my instances and queues etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to list all the existed queue in that account first. The queue might be deleted by someone else.

Comment: This should probably be a comment as it's not really an answer to the problem.